# ASP.NET Core making SOAP API request with WCF client how to add a Cookie header to the request?

Tags: api, wcf, asp.net-core, soap, session-cookies

So I am currently working on making SOAP API request to a service with WCF generated code "Client object", I am wondering how to set the Cookie header to the request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, we add the custom HTTP header by using `HttpRequestMessageProperty`. Please refer to the below code.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
try
{
    using (OperationContextScope ocs=new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
    {
        var requestProp = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        requestProp.Headers["myhttpheader"] = "Boom";
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestProp;
        var result = client.SayHelloAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
    }
```

**Result.**
[image]
WebOperationContext is a convenience wrapper around the OperationContext. At present, it hasn’t been implemented yet in the Aspnet Core.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2686
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: super man, thanks, i was really struggling to make it work with .net core, this worked perfectly

Comment: after a lot of struggle and search, this is the code that works and it also can be used with async/await. thanks a lot!